# Custom added Status Reason does not display in SSRS report via FilteredView

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-365

I recently have a problem, in which I can not see newly added status reasons in my custom report.
I have created a report based on `FilteredView` in which `status reason of opportunity` must display.
It just show the original status reason ( canceled ), but the others I have created does not display.
I should display them in a chart, but they do not appear.
As administrator its OK, and I can see them.
But other users can not see.
What is wrong?
Should I put some security role somewhere?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have second language.
And that field did not translate into the second language, and that was the cause of this.
I export translation, edit that and import that.
Problem solved!